# After effects | How do I copy an image source from layer to another programatically?

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions, after-effects-scripting

My comp setup is as follows:
- layer 1: image
- layer 2: duplicated from layer one

I'm looking for an expression or any other method (Could be a plugin recommendation) so when I change the image of layer 1, it automatically updates layer 2!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you mean:

Option 1:
If you put the image in Layer 1 inside a Comp, then any change to the image inside the Comp will change in both Layer 1 and Layer 2 (assuming you also put the Comp on Layer 2).

Option 2:
You could put a load of different images inside a comp, a different one on each frame.
Then in your master comp, place this comp, but assign Time Remap to the comp, to choose to hold on a specific frame.  Then when you want to change the held frame, just keyframe to the different time in your first comp.

Option 3: 
If you really mean to change the image programmatically, you could use something like [Templater Rig](https://aescripts.com/templater/), where you can set a load of different file paths to images, and then assign them to different comps programmatically.

Comment: Thanks @tomh, I'm more into option1 but would like to have a different effect for each image in each comp. Templater is perfect choice but pricy for this feature only.

Comment: I don't think you need any additional plugins for what you're trying to do.
Just place the different effects on layer 1, layer 2 whilst using the same comp in each layer?

Comment: This is great, but for some reasons when I duplicate the comp in the timeline, the copy doesn't follow the original in changes. only if the comp is in project directory and not imported to the time line then the method works. Once the duplicate imported it doesn't follow the changes.

Comment: how do you mean it doesn't follow the changes?  Duplicating a comp in the timeline is different from duplicating it in the project window. When you duplicate it in the timeline, both layers will reference a single source comp. If you duplicate the comp in the Project panel, it will make a unique copy of the comp.

Comment: That’s exactly what I wanted. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: No worries at all- I highly recommend this set of tutorials to learn more. It’s old but all of it is still relevant: http://www.videocopilot.net/basic/